# Obtain list of strings from column index of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, list, pandas, dataframe

First off, here is what my .xlsx timeseries data looks like:

[image: What the data looks like in excel]

and here is how I'm reading it:

```
def loaddata(filepaths):
    t1 = time.clock()
    for i in range(len(filepaths)):
        xl = pd.ExcelFile(filepaths[i])
        df = xl.parse(xl.sheet_names[0], header=0, index_col=2, skiprows=[0,2,3,4], parse_dates=True)
        df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all') 
        df = df.drop(['Decimal Year Day', 'Decimal Year Day.1', 'RECORD'], axis=1)
        df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(((df.index.asi8/(1e9*60)).round()*1e9*60).astype(np.int64)).values

        if i == 0:
            dfs = df
        else:
            dfs = concat([dfs, df], axis=1)

    t2 = time.clock()
    print "Files loaded into dataframe in %s seconds" %(t2-t1)

    return dfs

files = ["London Lysimeters corrected 5min.xlsx"]
data = loaddata(files)
```

What I need to be able to do is read the column labels AND units (row 2 and 3) as well as the values into a pandas dataframe, and be able to access the labels and units row as a list of strings. I can't seem to figure out how to load up both row 2 and 3 and have the time read in correctly into pandas datetimeindex, but it works fine if I only upload the labels. Also I've looked everywhere and can't figure out how to get the column headers as a list.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help with either of these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, get rid of that `for i in range(len(filepaths))`!  The pythonic way is `for i, filepath in enumerate(filepaths)`.  [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) gives a tuple so you can say `ExcelFile(filepath)` instead of `ExcelFile(filepaths[i])`.

I think your two problems are related.  If I'm reading your code correctly, when you include row 2 and 3 the dates can't be parsed since the timestamp column isn't homogenous.  It's not all timestamps.

You could use a [Hierarchical index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex) to get the data in `(column, label, unit)` format. It's probably easiest to first read in just the header information. Then read the data separately and set the columns after the fact (I don't have excel handy right now, but I think all the `read_csv` options I use are available to `xlrd` also):

```
In [7]: df_header = pd.read_csv('test.csv', nrows=2, index_col='three')

In [8]: df_header
Out[8]: 
               one      two    four
three                              
Timestamp  Decimal  Decimal  record
ts             ref      ref      rn

In [9]: df_data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=df_header.columns,
   ...:                       skiprows=4, parse_dates=True, index_col=2)

In [10]: df_data
Out[10]: 
                      one   two  four
2012-08-29 07:10:00  32.1  32.0   232
2012-08-29 09:10:00   1.1   1.2   233

In [11]: cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple([x] + df_header[x].tolist())
   ....:                                   for x in df_header])

In [12]: cols
Out[12]: 
MultiIndex
[one   Decimal  ref, two   Decimal  ref, four  record   rn ]

In [14]: df_data.columns = cols

In [15]: df_data
Out[15]: 
                         one      two    four
                     Decimal  Decimal  record
                         ref      ref      rn
2012-08-29 07:10:00     32.1     32.0     232
2012-08-29 09:10:00      1.1      1.2     233
```

This should get you to the point in your code where you start dropping columns and start concatenating.  Also take a look at the [developers docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#excel-files).  It looks like the syntax for reading excel files is getting cleaned up (much nicer!).  You might be able to use the `parse_cols` argument with a list of ints to avoid dropping columns later.

Oh and you can get the list of strings with `df_data.columns.tolist()`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do a double read as it takes 30-40s to load up each sheet and the program will need to load 12-16 sheets of the same size each time and even though the first read per file is small it still takes a fair bit of time to get going. However, being able to get the strings will be very handy as I can use them to create a combo box now and plot data, just without units at the moment. Thanks for this!

Comment: Maybe look into setting a chunk size equal to the header length and concatenate all but the first chunk.  That will split it into header, data while only opening each file once.